# Why cannot see the logout button in FB SSO for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios5

I am really new to the iOS application development. I am now integrating FB to my app. I followed the tutorial from fb_developer (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/).

Here is the code in my app delegate.m. I am wondering why I cannot see the logout button on the screen and I cannot get logged out.

```
#import "FBtestAppDelegate.h"
#import "FBtestViewController.h"

@implementation FBtestAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController=_viewController;
@synthesize facebook;



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Add the logout button
UIButton *logoutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
logoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 40);
[logoutButton setTitle:@"Log Out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonClicked)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.viewController.view addSubview:logoutButton];


// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId: @"400478970009544"
                               andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]){
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAcccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

// This part, the authorize method will bring you to the authorization page                              
if (![facebook isSessionValid])
    {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    }

return YES;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}


// Save the user credential, specifically the access token and the expiration date to the     user defaults
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAcessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

}

// Method that gets called when the logout button is pressed

```
- (void) fbDidLogout {
// Remove saved authorization information if it exists
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]) {
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

your app is not the only app using FB on device... there might be several other apps using FB information.... if you want to be logged out from FB within your app, then simply remove the access token from the user defaults (as it is happening in the fbDidLogout method in your code)...